# How do I make Spring Legacy project in Intellij?

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I'm new to spring trying to create spring legacy project. the only way I found from internet is create project with maven Archtype>right click on project folder > click "add framework support" > click spring MVC then spring MVC should be showed up when I click "add framework support" but it's missing how do I make spring legacy project or how do I add spring MVC into "add framework support" tap? All answers will be appreciated
p.s I'm using Intellij ultimate 2022.03

I tried re-create project with maven archtype

Answer (score 0):

As per the IntelliJ IDEA Documentation-> refer to this- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-support.html

Read all the contents under `Spring`.

Even you can use `Spring Initializr` provided by Spring to create new project and then you can import the project in IntelliJ.
refer to this- https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: trying to create spring MVC project just like create spring legacy project with spring MVC project template in STS. do you have any idea about this? sorry for being noob. I am kind of new to programming. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by just downgrade intellij to the old version 2021.03

create a Maven project without any archetype then add springframework dependency into pom.xml
manually typed the all of the configuration xml files then mapped all of those files to spring MVC artifact.

I guess if I downgrade to the way older version from now. like 2020.03 or something there will appear the Spring MVC tap in the "Add framework support" tap tho. I have no problem with this set up thus far